# Eclipse will not let me extend applet in my driver class so I can embed my program in HTML. Any solutions?

Tags: java, html, eclipse, applet

Trying to extend applet but it just keeps sending me back and forth between removing and adding the @SupressWarnings.

[image]

Comment: java applet deprecated in jdk 9. if you want use them ignore `@SupressWarnings` and continue coding

Answer (score 2):

You are using Java 11, applet support which was deprecated in Java 9 has been completely removed from Java 11 (see the [release notes](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/11-relnote-issues-5012449.html)). This is why `sun.applet.AppletViewer` cannot be found.

In any case most modern browsers won't run applets.

Comment: Thank you, what replaces it? How could u get these programs to run and embed in HTML?

Comment: Nothing. Java in the browser is dead.